# ElasticSearch 2.2.0 - ESIntegTestCase - ClassNotFoundException when executing groovy script in search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, groovy

I've been using Elastic 1.4.4, but we're now upgrading to 2.2.0. I am having trouble getting my integration tests to run. My integration test extends `org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase`:

```
@ESIntegTestCase.ClusterScope(scope = ESIntegTestCase.Scope.SUITE, numDataNodes = 1)
public abstract class AbstractApplicationTest extends ESIntegTestCase {
  ...
}
```

I can index documents without problems, but when I try searching with a script field, I get an error. I'm running my tests using sbt (I'm using the Play framework).

The error I'm getting is following:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [{
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "failed to compile groovy script"
        }],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [{
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "bokun",
            "node": "BNyjts9hTOicRgCAWGdKgQ",
            "reason": {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "Failed to compile inline script [if(_source.accumulated_availability != null){  for(item in _source.accumulated_availability){    if(start.compareTo(item.day) < 0 && (end == null || end.compareTo(item.day) >= 0)){      return item.day    }  }} else return null;] using lang [groovy]",
                "caused_by": {
                    "type": "script_exception",
                    "reason": "failed to compile groovy script",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "multiple_compilation_errors_exception",
                        "reason": "startup failed:\nCould not instantiate global transform class groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation specified at jar:file:/Users/ogg/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.4.4-indy.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation\n\nCould not instantiate global transform class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation specified at jar:file:/Users/ogg/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.4.4-indy.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation\n\n2 errors\n"
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

I'll reformat the "reason" message for readability:

```
startup failed:

Could not instantiate global transform class 
groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation 
specified at jar:file:/Users/ogg/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.4.4-indy.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  

because of exception 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation

Could not instantiate global transform class 
org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation 
specified at jar:file:/Users/ogg/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.4.4-indy.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  

because of exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation
```

What can cause this? As far as I can tell, I have this class in my classpath: `org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation`. 
I have the following dependencies in my build.sbt:

```
  "org.codehaus.groovy" % "groovy-all" % "2.4.4",
  "com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting" % "randomizedtesting-runner" % "2.3.0" % "test",
  "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-test-framework" % "5.4.1",
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "2.2.0" % "test" classifier "tests" withSources(),
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "2.2.0" withSources(),
  "org.elasticsearch.plugin" % "analysis-icu" % "2.2.0" % "test",
  "org.elasticsearch.module" % "lang-groovy" % "2.2.0" % "test"
```

...and I have the following in my EsIntegTestCase extension class:

```
@Override
protected Settings nodeSettings(int nodeOrdinal) {
    return Settings.settingsBuilder()
            .put(super.nodeSettings(nodeOrdinal))
            .put(IndexMetaData.SETTING_NUMBER_OF_SHARDS, 1)
            .put(IndexMetaData.SETTING_NUMBER_OF_REPLICAS, 1)
            .put(Node.HTTP_ENABLED, true)
            .put("script.groovy.sandbox.enabled", true)
            .put("script.engine.groovy.inline.search", true)
            .put("script.engine.groovy.inline.update", "true")
            .put("script.inline", true)
            .put("script.update", true)
            .put("script.indexed", true)
            .put("script.default_lang", "groovy")
            .build();
}

@Override
protected Collection<Class<? extends Plugin>> nodePlugins() {
    return pluginList(GroovyPlugin.class, AnalysisICUPlugin.class);
}
```

I'm completely stuck, and Google is unwilling to help! :slightly_smiling:

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
OGG

Comment: Add the stacktrace please

Comment: @Jens I don't really have a stack trace. The only error message I have is embedded in the error JSON result I get from elasticsearch (as pasted above):
startup failed:

Could not instantiate global transform class 
groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation 
...
because of exception 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation

Could not instantiate global transform class 
org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation   

because of exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation

Answer (score 3):

This is now solved.

The problem was actually that this was a SecurityException rethrown as ClassNotFoundException.

Using the instructions at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-security.html I created a security policy file and added permission for the following classes:

```
grant {
    permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "java.lang.Class";
    permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "org.codehaus.groovy.*";
    permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "groovy.*";
    permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "java.lang.*";
    permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "java.util.*";
    permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "java.math.BigDecimal";
    permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "org.joda.time.*";
};
```

And then I start the tests passing my security policy file on the command line:

`-Djava.security.policy=security.policy`

You can see the thread on the Elastic discussion forum which helped me reach this solution: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/2-2-0-esintegtestcase-classnotfoundexception-when-executing-groovy-script-in-search/43579